# Empty response running wordpress docker recipe on windows

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to run a basic wordpress app using Docker for windows.
I just followed the recipe here : https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` :

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.3'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DB}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}

    wordpress:
        depends_on:
            - db
        image: wordpress:latest
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        restart: always
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:${MYSQL_PORT}
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}

volumes:
    db_data:
```

And the `.env` file coming with it :

```
# DATABASE
MYSQL_DB=wordpress
MYSQL_USER=wordpress
MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress
MYSQL_PORT=3306

#WORDPRESS
WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d` everything works fine.
But when I try to reach `http://127.0.0.1:8080` I just got an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` again and again, even if I wait for hours (the doc says that installation can take several minuts in background, but nope !)

If I run `docker-compose up` I can see looping errors access denied for mysql users... Do I miss something on mysql users creation ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally made it.
It was a combination of two problems !

At first, we have to plug the wordpress container into the root mysql user, unless it won't have permissions to create tables and so on.

```
wordpress:
    depends_on:
        - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:${MYSQL_PORT}
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

Secondly, the `db_data` is a volume, so Docker keep it somewhere. When I ran a `docker volume ls` I just reognized dozens of volumes created during my multiple tries.

But I really think the main problem was wordpress access to database, which was blocking all the installation process.